# Ruby diff two hashes and merge in loop with cumulative sum

Tags: ruby, hash, diff, cumulative-sum, accumulator

help with ruby needed!

I have loop in with I collect data about PHP processes (PID, utimes). I have two hashes. First 'h1' looks like:

```
"domain1" => { :utime => 0, :last_seen => 0, :process_count => 0, :process_count_avg => 0 },
"domain2" => { :utime => 0, :last_seen => 0, :process_count => 0, :process_count_avg => 0 }
```

This is code for it:

```
h1[vhostname] ||= { :utime => 0, :last_seen => 0, :process_count => 0, :process_count_avg => 0 }
h1[vhostname][:utime] += utime_proc 
h1[vhostname][:last_seen] = 0
```

'vhostname' is string containing domain name. 
'utime_proc' is a utime value.

In every loop I sum all utimes for all processes of specific domain and output is Domain and its summed utime. But this distorts the real state.

What I need to do is to make cummulative sum of utimes for specific domain. To be the sum of utime for all current processes, but to add the sum of utime for all processes that have already ended. I will probably have to store pid processes for each subdomain utime, and if this process disappears, its last utime is added to the default value (the 'h1' hash): utime at that domain.

So, I create the two more hashes: 'h2' and 'h3'. The value of 'h3' is reseting in every loop round and this stores all PIDs for (sub)domain with its utimes like this:

```
h3[vhostname] = []
h3[vhostname] << {:pid => pid, :utime => utime_proc}
```

the 'h2' hash stores PIDs from all loop rounds before, same like 'h3' but its not reseting:

```
if not h2.key?(vhostname)
h2[vhostname] = []
h2[vhostname] << {:pid => pid, :utime => utime_proc}
end
```

The output hash should looks like:

```
{"domain1"=>[{:pid=>2, :utime=>20}, {:pid=>1, :utime=>10}], "domain2"=>[{:pid=>1, :utime=>10}, {:pid=>3, :utime=>30}]}
```

Now I need to help with: 
1. probably diff these two hashes and if PID for disseapear I need to remove them from 'h2' hash and its last utime value sum to utime value stored in 'h1'. 
2. I new PID appears for domain (in 'h3' is new pid and in 'h2' not yet), add this PID to 'h2' with its utime to particular domain.

And these are points what Im not able to do. I know I can simply do:

'h2-h3' or 'h3-h2' but I dont know what to do with the result and how to handle it.

Guys, can you help me, please? Short version of my code is bellow. Im still ruby-newbie.

```
h1 = {}
# Hash to collect PID and its utimes
h2 = {}

loop do  

# Hash to temporarly store PID and its utimes - in each cycle is reseting
h3 = {}

# Here I collect processes
#############
#############

# Collect PIDs and its utimes
# Store PIDs and its utimes temporarly - only for this loop round
h3[vhostname] = []
h3[vhostname] << {:pid => pid, :utime => utime_proc}

# is h2 empty? if so, this is probably first loop round
if not h2.key?(vhostname)
h2[vhostname] = []
h2[vhostname] << {:pid => pid, :utime => utime_proc}
else
# h2 is not empty, we can diff and sum
# PROBABLY PLACE I NEED TO HELP WITH

end
# Here I do some more magic with h1 and output the result with some delay
end
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the h2 and h3 hash structure to:

```
{:domain => "domain1.com", :pid => XXXX, :utime => YYYYY}
```

Comment: As I described, expected output is Domain name and its cumulative utime, in other words: how much of CPUs utime all PHP processes for particular domain consume during a run of this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not try to implement your logic, but dealing with hashes is what I will try to elucidate. For the sake of simplicity, I haven't looped, but just dealt with test data

```
domains = ['domain1','domain2','domain3']

h1 = {}
h2 = {}
# generate blank template for each domain
domains.each { |vhostname|
  h1[vhostname] ||= { :utime => 0, :last_seen => 0, :process_count => 0, :process_count_avg => 0 }
  h2[vhostname] ||= {}
}

# dummy loop
1.upto(5) {
  h3={}
  # start collecting data for each domain
  domains.each { |vhostname|
    # TEST DATA
    h3[vhostname] ||= {}
    1.upto(5) {
      _pid = rand(1..10)
      h3[vhostname][:"#{_pid}"] ||= {:utime => rand(9999)}
    }
    # TEST DATA

    h2[vhostname].merge!(h3[vhostname])
    h2[vhostname].each { |proc, details|
      unless h3[vhostname].key?(proc)
        h1[vhostname][:utime] = h1[vhostname][:utime] + details[:utime]
      end
    }
    h2[vhostname] = h2[vhostname].keep_if { |proc| h3[vhostname].key?(proc)}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Chiranjib, your code looks very useful. Can I ask you adjust hashes structure in your code to be same as mine? I updated my post and I specified a little bit more how hashes look like. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Brian, changed it a bit. You should grasp the idea and try implementing the logic yourself. Also, please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: Thanks one more time. I mean hash structure, not it names. For example this is my hash: "domain1" => [ {:pid => XXX, :utime => ZZZ }, {:pid => XXX1, :utime => ZZZ1 } ], "domain2" => [ {:pid => XXX, :utime => ZZZ }, {:pid => XXX1, :utime => ZZZ1 } ] and yours looks little bit different. As well my h1 hash looks little bit different. Sorry for this, Im really ruby beginner. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I thought you wanted cumulative utimes for a domain, looks like you also want to collect pid information for the domain? The question is very unclear here. In the comment above, 'domain1' is not a hash, but array of hashes. If this is the case, then h1 should have structure like h1 = {:domain1 => [...], :domain2 => [...]}

Comment: Yes, but for knowing cumulative utime for a domain I need to know also pids and its utime and to know, if which process is new or which is gone and based on this I can sum its utime to total utime count. Your example is fine but not fully correspond to my hashes and array of hashes. I updated my post one more time. h2 and h3 should looks like {"domain1"=>[{:pid=>2, :utime=>20}, {:pid=>1, :utime=>10}], "domain2"=>[{:pid=>1, :utime=>10}, {:pid=>3, :utime=>30}]} Please, check my codes example in my post one more time. Apologize for my unclear description

Comment: Changed my answer one more time, feels like I am writing your code for you now. Please close this question. Your problem seems more specific to application logic, and not related to Ruby (or any other language for that matter) Hope it helps!